# Insert image tag in checkboxes list

Tags: theming, forms, taxonomy-terms

A Form having a form element of term reference with checkboxes widget. I want to insert a image tag with each taxonomy term name,

For example here is the html of taxonomy term reference

`< div class="form-item form-type-checkbox
form-item-field-user-interest-und-24">
  < input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-user-interest-und-24"
name="field_user_interest[und][24]" value="24" checked="checked"
class="form-checkbox ajax-processed">
  < label class="option
like-taxonomy-term" for="edit-field-user-interest-und-24">-uejo
< /label>
< /div>`

so how can i insert image tag inside div tag so that its html become this

`< div class="form-item form-type-checkbox
form-item-field-user-interest-und-24">
  < input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-user-interest-und-24"
name="field_user_interest[und][24]" value="24" checked="checked"
class="form-checkbox ajax-processed">
  < label class="option
like-taxonomy-term" for="edit-field-user-interest-und-24">-uejo
< /label>
< img src="image=path" alt="image-text">
< /div>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to add a prefix or suffix with the field. See [Field Suffix in the Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#field_suffix), So your code might be:

```
$form['copy'] = array(
'#type' =>'checkbox', 
'#title' => t('my taxonomy term.'),
'#field_suffix' => '<img src="myimg.png" />',
);
```

You can use [field_prefix](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#field_prefix) if you want it to come before.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best option would be to use a custom module to perform a `hook_form_alter()` and add the image programmatically to the form array.

There are no exiting contrib modules that I am aware of that will do this for you, seeing as it is a very specific need that requires an individualized solution.

Comment: How i write my code in form alter so that image tag would be show as sibling with input and label tag.

Comment: The Form API provides for additional fields which you can put the image into.  Two examples are [#field_suffix](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#field_suffix) and [#field_prefix](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#field_prefix).